# Calculate endTime using startTime and testDuration

Tags: java, beanshell

I have the test start time (say 9:05:30) and total duration (say 5000 seconds) that a test should run.How to calculate the end time from start time and end time?

Comment: javascript and java have absolutely nothing to do with each other. as for the calculation: convert your time to seconds, add duration, convert new value back to time

Comment: Oops.I've tagged it by mistake.Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to be able to calculate if the test lasted the correct amount of time of 5000 seconds?

Comment: Actually, That's a part of it. I'm actually trying to automate the rampUp for given threads and test duration

Answer (score 2):

If you're using something like `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` from the Java 8 time API, you can use `plusSeconds`:

```
Instant startTime = ...
Instant endTime = startTime.plusSeconds(5000);
```

If you're using `Date` (oh, the horrors...), you can simply use `getTime`:

```
Date startTime = ...
Date endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5000));
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascipt you can do

```
console.time('testSomeCall');
//code here
console.timeEnd('testSomeCall');
```

in other languages usually you get the time or timestamp before your test and then after and do end - init, like this in this for java

```
long timeInit = System.currentTimeMillis();
//some code here
long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Ttotal time: " + (timeEnd - timeInit));
```

Comment: But I have the duration and start time. Need to calculate the end time.

Comment: take a look into http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp, you will need to do inititalTime + duration time to get the endTime

Answer (score 0):

```
String myTime = "9:05:20";

// before calculation
Date tempStartTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(myTime);
int hours = tempStartTime.getHours();
int minutes = tempStartTime.getMinutes();
int seconds = tempStartTime.getSeconds();
int elapsedSeconds = 5000;

// add seconds
int totalSeconds = seconds + elapsedSeconds;

// after calculation
Date tempEndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + totalSeconds);
hours = tempEndTime.getHours();
minutes = tempEndTime.getMinutes();
seconds = tempEndTime.getSeconds();

System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

// Output is 10:28:40
```

**How can 09:05:5020 be parsed as Date?**

the value is successfully parsed as the 5020th seconds, simply rolling over to next minute after each 60 seconds to accommodate the Out-Of-Bounds value. If you want to prevent this, call `setLenient(false);` on a `DateFormat` object before parsing (leniency is true by default).

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38379094/642706) is correct about using java.time rather than the old date-time classes. Here's more specific detail.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `Instant`

If just programmatically getting 5,000 seconds later from now, use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object as shown in Turner’s Answer. An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant later = Instant.now().plusSeconds( 5_000 );
```

## `LocalTime`

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. So this works only for generic 24-hour days, not realistic days with time zones that have anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "09:05:30" );
LocalTime later = lt.plusSeconds( 5_000 );
```

If hitting midnight, the result will roll-over into the early hours of the day starting with hour `00`, then `01`, and so on.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a realistic value that respects [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and so on, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).plusDays( 1 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "09:05:30" );
ZonedDateTime tomorrowAround9Am = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , lt , zoneId 0;
ZonedDateTime later = tomorrowAround9Am.plusSeconds( 5_000 );
```